# Borland С++ Builder 6 ошибка Access violation

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++builder

Задание из института, Из матрицы размером NхM получить вектор B, присвоив его k-му элементу значение 0, если все элементы k-го столбца матрицы нулевые, иначе 1.

вылетает на `delete []arrayMatrix[i];`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
upd
```

теперь что-то не так вот тут

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++){

            for(int j=0; j<m;j++){

            arrayMatrix[i][j]=StrToInt(StringGrid1->Cells[j+1][i+1]);
        if(arrayMatrix[i][j]==0){
            arrayVector[i]=1;
        }else{
            arrayVector[i]=0;
        }
    }
```

весь код

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>

#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
        int n=3;
        int m=3;
        std::vector<int> vect;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------



void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
        double **arrayMatrix, *arrayVector;
        int i, j;

        arrayMatrix = new double*[n];

        for(i=0; i<n;i++){
        arrayMatrix[i] = new double[n];
        arrayVector = new double[n];
        }

        for(int i=0; i<n;i++){

                for(int j=0; j<m;j++){

                arrayMatrix[i][j]=StrToFloat(StringGrid1->Cells[j+1][i+1]);
            if(arrayMatrix[i][0]==0){
                arrayVector[i]=1;
            }else{
                arrayVector[i]=0;
            }
        }
    }


        delete []arrayMatrix[i];
        delete []arrayMatrix;
        delete []arrayVector;

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{

         n = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
         m = StrToInt(Edit2->Text);


        StringGrid1->ColCount = n+1;

        StringGrid1->RowCount = m+1;

        StringGrid2->RowCount = n+1;

       //заполняет строчки и столбцы номерами индексов

        for(int i=1; i<=n;i++){
         StringGrid1->Cells[0][i]="i="+IntToStr(i);
        }

        for (int j=1;j<=m;j++){
        StringGrid1->Cells[j][0]="j="+IntToStr(j);
        }


}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: У вас ошибка тут for(i=0; i<n;i++){
        arrayMatrix[i] = new double[n];
        arrayVector = new double[n];  т.к матрица m*n а вы задаёте m*n.

Comment: Выравнивание кода бы хоть сделали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete []arrayMatrix[i];` вызывать надо в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

В строке

```
delete []arrayMatrix[i];
```

переменная i выходит за предел массива. Удалять нужно как и создаешь - в цикле:

```
for(i=0; i<n;i++){
   delete []arrayMatrix[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка тут, после new

```
 arrayMatrix = new double*[n];
    for(i=0; i<n;i++){
    arrayMatrix[i] = new double[n];
```

т.к матрица m x n а вы задаёте n x n.

Comment: `arrayMatrix = new double*[m];
    for(i=0; i<n;i++){
    arrayMatrix[i] = new double[n];`
так правильно?

Comment: сложно быстро сказать, или так или наоборот. с delete проблема - может его пока закомментировать (приведёт к утечке памяти, пока не существенно). Сначало нужно разобраться что б за границы массива не выходила.